# Homebrew not updating the version of my package

Tags: macos, homebrew

I am a homebrew novice and have a tap with a single package, mark-on-mac (https://github.com/sjbonner/homebrew-tap). The tap is simply a wrapper for the executable of Program MARK for the analysis of mark-recapture data that defines the location for the gcc libraries.

I have updated the formula several times (now on v0.0.7), but the command

```
brew install mark-on-mac
```

always finds and installs version v0.0.3. In order to install the up-to-date version I have to specify my tap

```
brew install sjbonner/tap/mark-on-mac
```

Here's a listing showing the behaviour when I don't and then do specify the tap

```
Simons-MBP:homebrew-tap sbonner$ brew info mark-on-mac
mark-on-mac: stable 0.0.3
Command-line version of Dr. Gary White's mark-recapture software
http://warnercnr.colostate.edu/~gwhite/mark/mark.htm
Not installed
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/mark-on-mac.rb
Simons-MBP:homebrew-tap sbonner$ brew install mark-on-mac
==> Downloading https://github.com/sjbonner/mark-on-mac/archive/v0.0.3.tar.gz
==> Downloading from https://codeload.github.com/sjbonner/mark-on-mac/tar.gz/v
                                                                           0.8#                                                                          2.1########                                                                  12.1###############                                                           22.2######################                                                    31.3###########################                                               38.5##################################                                        48.4##########################################                                59.2#################################################                         69.1########################################################                  79.0################################################################          89.7######################################################################## 100.0%
  /usr/local/Cellar/mark-on-mac/0.0.3: 5 files, 4.0MB, built in 6 seconds
Simons-MBP:homebrew-tap sbonner$ brew uninstall mark-on-mac
Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/mark-on-mac/0.0.3... (5 files, 4.0MB)
Simons-MBP:homebrew-tap sbonner$ brew info sjbonner/tap/mark-on-mac
sjbonner/tap/mark-on-mac: stable 0.0.7
Command-line version of Dr. Gary White's mark-recapture software
http://warnercnr.colostate.edu/~gwhite/mark/mark.htm
Not installed
From: https://github.com/sjbonner/homebrew-tap/blob/master/mark-on-mac.rb
Simons-MBP:homebrew-tap sbonner$ brew install sjbonner/tap/mark-on-mac
==> Installing mark-on-mac from sjbonner/tap
==> Downloading https://github.com/sjbonner/mark-on-mac/archive/v0.0.7.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/sbonner/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/a0310eb4eafbf40481bd5f010d2e369da2f91c41a203b508c340bfad893fd501--mark-on-mac-0.0.7.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/mark-on-mac/0.0.7: 5 files, 4MB, built in 3 seconds
Removing: /Users/sbonner/Library/Caches/Homebrew/mark-on-mac--0.0.3.tar.gz... (1.7MB)
Simons-MBP:homebrew-tap sbonner$
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening? Why does v0.0.3 get installed by default? How can I stop this?

Thanks in advance!

Simon

Answer (score 0):

It seems the local repository `sjbonner/tap` is outdated. You need to sync your local repo with the remote one.

```sh
# cd into the local repo
cd "$(brew --repo sjbonner/tap)"

# find out the latest commit locally
git log -s -1
# compare the commit with your remote repo

# if the repo is outdated, run
brew update
```